# slow cooker pot roast with carrots and potatoes

Tags: temperature

Slow cooker recipe for above says 6 hour on high,but I prefer to do it on low, go to work and come back with dinner being around 6:30.

How many hours on low should I set the crock pot for?

Comment: Might be worth adding how long you will be out the house, the idea behind a slow cooker is that you can leave them unattended for hours on end (I believe they work a bit like the bottom oven of an aga with a crock pot in) - With this in mind, it might not matter if you're out for 8 instead of 6. The other option might be to get a timer socket switch which will just turn the crock pot off for the last 1.5 hours (not recommended you leave it below 140F for more than 2 hours)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a joint of pork, you shouldn't - they have to be cooked on high to get a high enough internal temperature.

For other meats most of my books say you should roughly double the time if cooking on low, so 10-12 hours, with the lower end assuming a good preheat on high and browning the ingredients first. But there's no need to set a timer. A stew will keep well indefinitely on low, and this will stop it cooling down too much if you're delayed.